# Python extract a specific attachment from email

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to achieve the following:

I have an email object (eml) which can contain multiple attachments like zip/images/txt etc.
I want to download only a specific attachment and not all the attachments from this object.

I have tried the following code:

```
import email
import mimetypes
import uuid
import os

m = email.message_from_file(open('hello.eml'))
for part in m.walk():
filename = part.get_filename()
print('fileName: ', filename)
if part.get_content_type() == 'multipart/mixed' and not filename:
    number_of_attachments = (len(part.get_payload()) - 1)
    print('number_of_attachments: ', number_of_attachments)
    for attachment in range(number_of_attachments):
        tmp_name = str(uuid.uuid4())
        fp = open('.' + tmp_name, 'wb')
        attachment += 1
        fp.write(part.get_payload()[attachment].get_payload(decode=True))
        fp.close()
```

This extracts all the attachments.
Is there a way to filter only specific attachment and process that.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand your problem. `part.get_payload()` returns a list, according to your own code. This means you don't have to iterate over all elements, but you can address any element inside the list independently `part.get_payload()[0]`, `part.get_payload()[1]` ...

Comment: What is the issue, specifically?

Comment: What I need to identify is that inside the list of attachments I need to filter a specific attachment by a name.. I am not really sure how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the following way.

```
 import email
 import mimetypes
 import uuid
 import os

 m = email.message_from_file(open('hello.eml'))
 for part in m.walk():
 filename = part.get_filename()
 print('fileName: ', filename)
 if part.get_content_type() == 'multipart/mixed' and not filename:
   number_of_attachments = (len(part.get_payload()) - 1)
   print('number_of_attachments: ', number_of_attachments)
   for attachment in range(number_of_attachments):
       filteredFile = m.get_payload()[attachment]
       if filteredFile.get_content_type() == 'text/html':
            print("Search successful.")
       else:
            print("Search unsuccessful.")
```

Thanks all for your inputs!